# Not able to upload more then 5GB video file into AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I’m using AWS to upload videos from my App.

I can able to upload up to 5 GB single video without any problem with AWSS3TransferUtilityTask.

My requirement is I want to upload **more than 5 gb video file.(e.g  7GB, 10GB , 13GB)**

I’ve tried with **AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadTask** to upload more then 5 gb files. After completing more then 60% of upload I'm getting an error   **(NSURLErrorDomain error -1001).**

```
// Completion Handler

let completionHandler : AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadCompletionHandlerBlock? =
                        { (task, error) -> Void in

                            if ((error) != nil)
                            {
                                print("------------------>",error?.localizedDescription ?? "")

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("File uploaded successfully")
                            }
                        }


//Expression

let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression()
                        expression.progressBlock =  progress

//Content Type

let contentType = "video/mp4"


let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

                        transferUtility.uploadUsingMultiPart(fileURL: uploadingFileURL, bucket: bucket, key: path + filename, contentType: contentType, expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler)                     

                    }
                    else {
                        print(" session out----->",jsonData)
                    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the error, please.

Comment: @hephalump  I'm getting this error. **Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**

Comment: @jagajevanan I'm getting the same issue, did you manage to solve it?